# Disallow using comma operator

Tags: c++, comma-operator

I never use the comma operator.
But sometimes, when I write some recursions, I make a stupid mistake: I forget the function name. That's why the last operand is returned, not the result of a recursion call.

Simplified example:

```
int binpow(int a,int b){
    if(!b)
        return 1;
    if(b&1)
        return a*binpow(a,b-1);
    return (a*a,b/2); // comma operator
}
```

Is it possible get a compilation error instead of incorrect, hard to debug code?

Comment: This is too much. You want the compiler to do every job for you?

Comment: @Nawaz I want to make as more erorrs as possible compilation error.

Comment: @Nawaz, I assume you would do away with all compiler messages? ;-)

Comment: "return (a*a,b/2); // comma operator" That line should scream at you and make your eyes burn. You don't need a compiler error, you just need to _read_ the freaking line.

Comment: @DanielDaranas if I understand the question correctly @RiaD added the comment to point out that he had inadvertently used the comma operator because he had forgotten the function name. ie: he meant `return binpow(a*a,b/2);`, but instead made a mistake and wrote `return (a*a,b/2);` which invoked the comma operator rather than causing a compilation error

Comment: @SteveLorimer I understand. But I assumed that it is necessary to review the code, and the simplest code review would have detected that mistake.

Comment: @DanielDaranas humans make mistakes - better to force a compiler error than rely on a code review to throw up the error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, with a caveat. The gcc has the `-Wunused-value` warning (or error with `-Werror`). This will take effect for your example since `a*a` has no effect. Compiler result:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int binpow(int, int)’:
test.cpp:6:43: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

However, this won't catch single-argument calls and calls where all arguments have side effects (like `++`). For example, if your last line looked like

```
return (a *= a, b/2);
```

the warning would not be triggered, because the first part of the comma statement has the effect of changing `a`. While this is diagnoseable for a compiler (assignment of a local, non-volatile variable that is not used later) and would probably be optimized away, there is no gcc warning against it.

For reference, the full `-Wunused-value` entry of the manual with Mike Seymours quote highlighted:

> Warn whenever a statement computes a result that is explicitly not used. To suppress this warning cast the unused expression to void. **This includes an expression-statement or the left-hand side of a comma expression that contains no side effects.** For example, an expression such as x[i,j] will cause a warning, while x[(void)i,j] will not.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sure, but the left operand of the comma has no effect and is ignored, which is caught by -Wunused-value.

Comment: @thton: No, that is not unused value. I don't think that will give any warning. Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: @Nawaz: He's right. `a*a` is quite obviously an unused value.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes. Copied verbatim from the output of g++ Debian 4.6.1-15.

Comment: @Nawaz: whether or not it's technically an unused value (which I'm fairly sure it is), that GCC option catches it. From their [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused_002dvalue-322): "This includes an expression-statement or the left-hand side of a comma expression that contains no side effects."

Comment: Of course there is, and gcc certainly warns about it: `warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: Of course it's an unused value. Show me where it's being used; I dare you.

Answer (score 2):

gcc lets you specify **-Wunused-value** which will warn you if the LHS of a comma operator has no side effects.