# How to avoid/check this very sinister error-source in C++

Tags: c++

recently I've stumbled on a bug as a result of the combination typo, comma-operator, default value. A term had a lot of parenthesis and commas. One comma was placed one parenthesis too far. The term was still a valid C++ code but the returned value was wrong.
In simplified version the error looked like this:

```
int intValue = MyString.toInt(),16;
```

The method `toInt` has a default parameter for number-base (default 10).
The variable `intValue` would be always 16.

So the question is, is there any style-guide rule to avoid such bugs or a c++ checker/compiler rule to help finding such bugs in code?

**EDIT**

Ok, I've changed the code a little bit to make more sense for comma:

```
char * MyString("0x42");
int intValue = stringToInt(MyString),16;
```

P.S.
Please don't blame me for not using std::string and streams. The code is only for simplified demonstration. :-)

Comment: One could argue that any decent compiler would warn about the comma operator, but by that definition, there aren't very many decent compilers.

Comment: What does the simplified version look like _after the fix_? What was the _intended_ role of the comma?

Comment: I cannot see the intended role of the comma in this "simplified" example either.

Comment: In any case this is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139956/disallow-using-comma-operator

Comment: @Joe That duplicate shows horrible code. In this question, `int intValue = MyString.toInt(),16;` is totally awful, too, so I wonder what was the OP thinking (hence my comment). You can type that line by accident, but surely you should _read_ your code after writing it and such lines should scream at you "hey! I'm _wrong!".

Comment: @DanielDaranas Yes, both examples are horrible and could be avoided by simply reading the code one writes. Doesn't mean this isn't a duplicate, no?

Comment: @Joe Indeed it looks like it could be a _similar_ problem of "unintended use of the comma operator", but without the OP answering why he typed a comma in the first place, I can't tell.

Comment: @DanielDaranas You are right, in "simplified version" the comma makes no sense. The ecample is only for demonstrating how the obviously (in this simple code) wrong code compiles perfectly and even the value may be plausible. The real code was a call of a function which user itself a function-return value from other terms.

Comment: @Joe: Looks like the same problem-cause indeed. And the solution is the same :-) On the other hand, the other question is pretty radical. Why would one dare to disable comma operator? The author is trying to avoid potential user errors in C++ code by reducing C++ functionality.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Then the technique you need to prevent mistakes is expressed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18012083/96780): *Keep it simple*. Today it is a comma operator, tomorrow it will be another thing that you won't spot if you don't keep your expressions simple. (By the way, I still fail to understand your explanation of the mysterious "real code".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GCC, the `-Wunused-value` should give a warning in this case, as the return value of `MyString.toInt()` is not used. That flag should help avoid most such errors. To actually get the warning may require adding the `__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))` attribute to the `toInt` method.

In any case, as shown the simplified example causes an "expected unqualified-id before numeric constant" compile error unless parentheses are added as follows `int intValue = (MyString.toInt(),16);`

Comment: Thanks! that's what I was looking for. I was not aware, that this argument would catch this kind of errors too.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is:

- **Readability and clarity always come first.** Do not combine several simple expressions into a complex one. Instead, **keep it simple**. The fact that you post the simplified code, instead of the actual version, scares me. Anything that is too complex to post here should not go in your code.
- **Do not use default parameters.** I don't find them to add much value for the readability they substract.
- **Do not use the comma operator**.

Also, perform **code reviews** (the mere fact that a comma operator is present should have triggered a review comment); **unit test** your code; and use **assertions** to express preconditions and postconditions.

If you follow this advice, just **reading your code after you type it** will make erroneous lines scream at your eyes.

Comment: Code reviews and unit tests would help, yes. But the question is about how he would detect accidental use of default parameters and the comma operator, so "don't use them" isn't an answer. "Keep it simple" is good general advice, but the example code is already very simple so that's not really an answer either. And stating that "Anything that is too complex to post here should not go in your code" is ridiculous. If my code consisted only of simple assignment statements like this, it wouldn't get a lot done.

Comment: @Ben It _is_ what I do to prevent the risks associated to them. For me, it is an answer, and one which works.

Comment: Concerning the 3rd: what do you mean exactly? One shouldn't overwrite it as suggested by Scott Meyers ore one shouldn't use also things like: for( mycontiner::const_iterator it= mycontiner.begin(), end = mycontainer.end(); it!=end; ++it){...}? Concerning the 2nd: in my error code the default parameter was actually declared by a library-function. I was even not aware of it first. Concerning the 1st: in general true, but complex things remain complex. In automotive industry you'll often find code where each single line is simple, but amount of lines raises again the complexity.

Comment: @Valentin (3) I mean do not use it, but the "for" statement syntax could be an excepcion, as long as it is well controlled and reviewed. (2) I cannot modify library functions, of course, so I just double-check calls to them, devoting a special attention to guarantee the correct use of third party code. (1) The rule is part of the book "C++ Coding Standards" (Sutter/Alexandrescu). No domain is an excuse for unneeded complexity at the instruction or function level - you can always handle that with layers and composition. I've worked in complex domains, I've done complex projects.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: It may sound very arrogant, but I don't trust too much people, who are too busy writing books and giving lectures. I remember Michael Feathers giving lectures on unit-testing at Siemens and being very helpless in practical part as he faced with questions and code from daily praxis. Sutter and Alexandresku used to be cool. But, why of all guys should I trust those, who invent so strange C++ syntax-usage, that even Stroustrup can't recognise the code as C++? :-)

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz I don't take everything anyone writes without criticism, but I find that particular advice from Sutter/Alexandrescu (and most of the content in the mentioned book) useful. I follow advice which which I find useful. I don't use smart pointers and operator overloading, for example.